# What is $\{ f \in F_{p^m}[x_1, \ldots, x_n] : f(a) = 0, \forall a \in A^n\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

As the title suggests, I am interested in knowing if there is a neat description of the ideal of polynomials that vanish on affine $n$ space over a finite field with $p^m$ elements. Is there a way to describe a minimal generating set, or at least how many element are necessary to generate this ideal for a given $n$ and $m$?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that you can't find any such polynomials if you are talking about affine n-space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ as $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, which many people consider the right definition.

Comment: Dear @KReiser: don't worry, even people who know the "right" definition are open-minded enough to know what AreaMan means. If one must be pedantic, one would say "polynomials vanishing on the rational points of $\mathbb A^n_{\mathbb F^{p^m}}$" or briefly "on $\mathbb A^n(\mathbb F^{p^m})$" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $q=p^m$ the required ideal is $\langle x_1^q-x_1,x_2^q-x_2,\cdots,x_n^q-x_n\rangle$.